# So how does exit() work?

Tags: c, exit

If I use `exit()`, GCC doesn't give a warning:

```
int main()
{
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

If we use any other function, we will definitely meet such a warning:

```
warning: control reaches end of non-void function
```

How does `exit()` make the parent function get its return value without using `return()`, which the compiler makes?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On GNU libc, `exit` is declared with `__attribute__((__noreturn__))`, which tells gcc that the function does not return.

Comment: @Chris Jester-Young,can you elaborate more about `__attribute__((__noreturn__))`?

Comment: @compile-fan: google is your friend: http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/gnu-c-attributes.html

Comment: so `__attribute__((__noreturn__))` actually tells gcc to take it as `return` statement?

Comment: @compile-fan: No, it tells the compiler that the function will not return, thus control will never reach the end of main, thus no warning.

Comment: @compile-fan: Try this: `int main() {exit(0); printf("Peek-a-boo!\n");}`. "Peek-a-boo!" is not printed.

Comment: @,Ed S.  how does it return `EXIT_SUCCESS` to parent function if it never returns?

Comment: No, it tells gcc that the function will never return. ("exit" causes the program to exit, so it'll never return to the caller.) Because of that, it doesn't matter that the caller itself ("main", in other words) doesn't have a return statement.

Comment: @compile-fan: Because `exit` is specified to deliver its argument to the parent process. Really, the C library initialisation code really just invokes your `main` this way: `exit(main(argc, argv, envp))`, so whether your `main` returns or not doesn't affect whether `exit` gets called.

Answer (score 3):

From [the docs:](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/exit/)

> The status argument is returned to the host environment.

And

> Issuing a return statement from the main function is equivalent to calling the exit function with the return value as its argument.

This is implemented (in this case) via a function declaration attribute (`__noreturn__`) which tells the compiler that it can be treated as a return (or, more correctly, that the function will not return, so control will never reach the end of main).

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
 exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

have

```
 return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

Comment: @Dietrich - Did you notice the question was changed before your comment but after my answer?

Comment: The parentheses are required here (exit is a function): exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

The parentheses don't do anything here (return is a operator): return(EXIT_SUCCESS);

Using parentheses with return is kind of like using them here: (1);

Comment: @davep - sure, it is just style.  I could make some crazy argument about macros blah blah blah -- but I'm not going to bother -- I always like return statements with the `()`, if they had a value/expression or not.

Comment: It might confuse beginners.

Comment: No idea what you mean @nikeee

Comment: Using parentheses on return might lead beginners to confuse the return keyword with a function. So it's not the best choose on an explanatory sample.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you failed to include `stdlib.h`, and that you're not compiling with `-std=c99`. In C99, `main` implicitly returns 0 if you run off the end of it.